# Tikz picture appears at the wrong location inside the document

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I haven't found any question on this but I'm having problems when placing a Tikz picture in a document. It's enclosed in a Figure environment, and it uses `\centerfloat` to center it, with some code in the preamble since it's not a Memoir, but an Article class.

In my MWE I added the picture between two Lorem Ipsums, but when typesetting, it appears before both of them. What is happening and how can I solve it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\centerfloat}{%
  \parindent \z@
  \leftskip \z@ \@plus 1fil \@minus \textwidth
  \rightskip\leftskip
  \parfillskip \z@skip}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={align=center, fill=white, draw=black, thick, rectangle, outer sep=0mm, inner sep=0mm},
    rect/.style={minimum height=8mm},
    recv/.style={text width=2.5cm, rotate=90},
}

\begin{document}

    FIRST Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet ante id augue faucibus maximus sit amet vel lacus. Suspendisse potenti. Nullam metus nunc, auctor vel rutrum sed, sollicitudin vitae ante. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ornare elit dui, sed aliquet erat pharetra ac. Nullam viverra ipsum tincidunt est cursus, at elementum neque congue. Aliquam tempor lorem ac eros mollis accumsan. Quisque vulputate consectetur ex at mattis. Ut aliquam, ligula at placerat elementum, lorem mauris convallis ante, vel faucibus nulla leo vel odio. Quisque nec ullamcorper ipsum.\\

\begin{figure}
    \centerfloat
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rect, text width=4cm] (prop) at (0,0) {proposition};
    \node[rect, text width=12cm, left=0mm of prop, anchor=east] (ent) {entity};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

SECOND Nullam et efficitur justo. Donec sodales velit sit amet lorem varius tempus. Nulla vitae leo justo. Phasellus rhoncus egestas dui, in rutrum nisi ullamcorper sit amet. Aliquam eget imperdiet dolor. Morbi quis hendrerit erat. Nulla ornare purus ac sollicitudin dapibus.

\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: figure is a float environment, and floats have a tendency to float away. http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=floats

Comment: why define `\centerfloat` rather than use the standard `\centering` ? The only reason for using `figure` is to allow the figure to move, if you do not want that, just use `tikzpicture` directly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because `\centering` doesn't work. And without `figure`, I don't know how to add a proper caption.

Comment: Why not just add a placement specifier, `\begin{figure}[!htbp] ...` for example?

Comment: Oh because your figure is wider than the page. Hmm `\makebox` is the standard way to centre that, although it isn't clear that allowing things to over-print the physical page boundaries without any warning is necessarily a good thing. There are lots of ways of captioning things eg `capt-of` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, I could reduce the picture I don't need it that big... Or maybe I could do the same with a standard tabular environment?

Comment: Is that your real use case just two words in boxes, you could just use two `framebox` no need for tikz or tabular at all.

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/4778) helped, and I see @AboAmmar also mentioned it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The actual picture is a bit bigger, I cut most of the picture to make the code shorter. :)

Answer (score 0):

`figure` is used specifically if you want the figure to float.

To add a proper caption, use `captionof`.

Try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\centerfloat}{%
  \parindent \z@
  \leftskip \z@ \@plus 1fil \@minus \textwidth
  \rightskip\leftskip
  \parfillskip \z@skip}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={align=center, fill=white, draw=black, thick, rectangle, outer sep=0mm, inner sep=0mm},
    rect/.style={minimum height=8mm},
    recv/.style={text width=2.5cm, rotate=90},
}

\begin{document}

    FIRST Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet ante id augue faucibus maximus sit amet vel lacus. Suspendisse potenti. Nullam metus nunc, auctor vel rutrum sed, sollicitudin vitae ante. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In ornare elit dui, sed aliquet erat pharetra ac. Nullam viverra ipsum tincidunt est cursus, at elementum neque congue. Aliquam tempor lorem ac eros mollis accumsan. Quisque vulputate consectetur ex at mattis. Ut aliquam, ligula at placerat elementum, lorem mauris convallis ante, vel faucibus nulla leo vel odio. Quisque nec ullamcorper ipsum.\\

\begin{centerfloat}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rect, text width=4cm] (prop) at (0,0) {proposition};
    \node[rect, text width=12cm, left=0mm of prop, anchor=east] (ent) {entity};

\end{tikzpicture}}
\captionof{figure}{Sample picture}
\end{centerfloat}

SECOND Nullam et efficitur justo. Donec sodales velit sit amet lorem varius tempus. Nulla vitae leo justo. Phasellus rhoncus egestas dui, in rutrum nisi ullamcorper sit amet. Aliquam eget imperdiet dolor. Morbi quis hendrerit erat. Nulla ornare purus ac sollicitudin dapibus.

\end{document}
```

[image]